# Use SSH to copy files from one webserver to another

Tags: ssh

I am logged in on a webserver and want to push the files to another webserver via FTP/port 21.

I tried it with this:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 21' license.txt user@ip:/httpdocs/
```

My assumption is that license.txt is pushed to /httpdocs/ on the other server, but nothing happens. Normally I must have been prompted to enter the password for the user on the remote ip address, hm?

Comment: What's the reason you want to use FTP/port 21? I only ask because FTP/21 is not secure, so it would defeat the purpose of using with rysnc ssh, which suggests you want some security. So it seems you might be doing contradictory things, can you explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @user454038 I can not connect to the FTP server with another port. SFTP is not supported says my FTP client. The reason why I want to use SSH, the transfer from server to server is much faster than downloading and uploading with my local maschine.